# Добрый день, подскажите плиз как реализовать логику в корзине opencart 2.2

Tags: opencart

Когда добавляешь от  трех разных товаров в корзину ,чтобы оно считало по оптовой цене каждого товара??

Comment: В сторону сторонних модулей не смотрите?

Comment: есть модуль только на дисконт от общей суммы на товаров..